# How to use implicit conversion instead of structural typing when only one collection method is needed

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, structural-typing

I have a method in which I only need to access one method (`appended`, or `:+`) of a type. I want to be able to use both a custom case class and a normal `List`. Coming from a TypeScript background, I know how to do this using structural typing:

```scala
case class CustomContainer[T](data: List[T]) {
  def :+(other: T): CustomContainer[T] = copy(data = data :+ other)
}

def append[T, A <: { def :+(other: T): A }](appendable: A, other: T): A = appendable :+ other

append(List(1,2,3), 4) // List(1,2,3,4)
append(CustomContainer(List(1,2,3)), 4) // CustomContainer(List(1,2,3,4))
```

However, I also know there are performance and maintainability disadvantages to using structural types. I'd like to find a better way, so I'm trying to do this using traits instead, but the sticking point is that I can't make `List` extend some trait that I defined. I have a feeling the answer is implicit conversion, but I can't figure out how to implicitly convert something to a trait, which is an abstract type.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```scala
trait Appendable[T, C] {
  def :+(other: T): C
}

case class CustomContainer[T](data: List[T]) extends Appendable[T, CustomContainer[T]] {
  override def :+(other: T): CustomContainer[T] = copy(data = data :+ other)
}

implicit def listToAppendable[T](list: List[T]): Appendable[T, List[T]] = ??? // What goes here?

def append[T, A <: Appendable[T, A]](appendable: A, other: T): A = appendable :+ other

append(List(1,2,3), 4) // List(1,2,3,4)
append(CustomContainer(List(1,2,3)), 4) // CustomContainer(List(1,2,3,4))
```

What goes in the `???` spot? Alternatively is there a better way to do this?

I am on Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: You want a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) -  check [this](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) for a comparison with other forms of polymorphism. - The trick here, is that you should not convert a **List** into an **Appendable** _(that would be a **magnet**)_, rather you should provide an evidence that **List** is **Appendable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type class for this:

```
final case class CustomContainer[T](data: List[T])

trait Appendable[T, C[_]] {
  def specialAppend(other: T, acc: C[T]): C[T]
}
object Appendable {
  implicit def listAppendable[A]: Appendable[A, List] = new Appendable[A, List] {
     override def specialAppend(other: A, acc: List[A]): List[A] = other :: acc
  }

  implicit def customContainerAppendable[A]: Appendable[A, CustomContainer] = new Appendable[A, CustomContainer] {
    override def specialAppend(other: A, acc: CustomContainer[A]): CustomContainer[A] = acc.copy(data = other :: acc.data)
  }
}

object Foo {
  implicit class AppendableOps[A, C[_]](val c: C[A]) {
    def :+!(elem: A)(implicit appendable: Appendable[A, C]): C[A] = appendable.specialAppend(elem, c)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(List(1,2,3,4) :+! 6)
    println(CustomContainer(List(1)) :+! 2)
    ()
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
List(6, 1, 2, 3, 4)
CustomContainer(List(2, 1))
```

Comment: `append` is a common method on collections in Scala, so I wouldn't want it to clash. I'll rework this for better naming

Comment: I personally would say that is actually a good reason for use that name.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez But it may overload with existing collections and not work.

Comment: Why? it shouldn't like `map` from **cats** doesn't crash. If the type already has an `:+` then the compiler will not search for extensions. - Also, the `implicit class` should be a `value class` too to avoid instantiation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I just got bit by this since `:++` is defined on `IterableOnce` and the signatures overload, that's exactly what I mean. `AnyVal` is nice but not necessary for the answer

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks for the answer! With your example, what exactly is happening when you say `new Appendable`? How can you use `new` with a trait? Also, is there any reason to do the implicit conversion from `CustomContainer` rather than extending `Appendable` directly?

Comment: @Ian When I write `new Appendable` it creates an [Anonymous Class](https://www.james-willett.com/scala-anonymous-classes/). This generates less boilerplate as you don't have to create an additional class which extends `Appendable`. The reason we don't inherit `Appendable`, but provide it as an [implicit parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) is that by doing it this way, we can: 1) Use it on classes we don't own (such as `List[A]`), 2) The compiler will automatically inject the instance in scope to our method at runtime, or fail compilation if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov [can't reproducde](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/zUSFPElwQgmNA5fClqfVxw/2)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Try using `:++` as the extension method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov uhm weird, oh well, whatever.